# How to recollect network information from Ubuntu to use it on Freebsd?

Tags: ubuntu, freebsd, configuration

FreeBSD and other BSD systems, required certain network information at installation time, like if I will use a DHCP server, or the IP address, subnet mask, IP address of default gateway, domain name of the network, IP addresses of the network’s DNS servers, etc.

When I install Ubuntu, I do not need to provide this information: in some way, Ubuntu recollect that data and use it, given the impression that the system "just works". I understand that under the hood Ubuntu just automatize something that the BSD developers thought it will be enough to just ask the user. But because I do not know this information beforehand, I will like to know where Ubuntu store this information, so I can use it to install FreeBSD on the same machine that now I have Ubuntu.

What I want to do is to move to FreeBSD (currently, I'm using it inside a VirtualBox inside Ubuntu), but I hit that wall.

I hope someone can point me in the right direction

Comment: Cross posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67288485/how-to-recollect-network-information-from-ubunto-to-use-it-on-freebsd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Ubuntu uses [Networkmanager](https://ubuntu.com/core/docs/networkmanager). In [FreeBSD](https://docs.freebsd.org/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/bsdinstall-network.html) you configure the network manually. If you *"do not need to provide this information when you install Ubuntu"* means default DHCP works for you. See [5. Network Configuration. FreeBSD Quickstart Guide for Linux® Users](https://docs.freebsd.org/en/articles/linux-users/index.html#network) how to configure ethernet DHCP in FreeBSD. If you need more details from Network Manager use [nmcli](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/nmcli.1.html). Read [32.3. Wireless Networking](https://docs.freebsd.org/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/network-wireless.html) on how to configure WiFi in FreeBSD. Generally, in FreeBSD, you'll have to understand advanced details e.g. [Chapter 32. Advanced Networking](https://docs.freebsd.org/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/advanced-networking.html) to configure them.